# jQueryUi dialog stuck in top left corner (and not movable)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, position, jquery-dialog

So I have a simple jQueryUi dialog that won't center, and it can't be moved either.

The error message I get in my console refers to

```
jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:36
```

so that doesn't tell me much, just that some parameter passed to some jQueryfunction was invalid:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'curCSS' jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:36
a.fn.position jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:36
p.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
a.fn.position jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:36
a.widget._position jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:156
a.widget.open jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:156
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:17
p.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
a.widget.bridge.a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js:17
openMediaLibrary 6:456
onclick 6:187
```

The dialog div looks like this:

```
<div id="mediaLibrary" title="Bildgalleri">
     <iframe width="950px" height="500px" src="{{ path('ImageGallery') }}" style="border:0;" /></iframe>
</div>
```

Dialog initialized here...

```
$( "#mediaLibrary" ).dialog({
    height: 550,
    width:980,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    position: { my: "center", at: "center" },
});
```

...and opened here

```
$( "#mediaLibrary" ).dialog( "open" );
```

Comment: Side note: you close your iframe twice: `<iframe /></iframe>`

Comment: try using latest jquery ui library

Comment: new version did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using all the params for `position`. The default of a dialog is centered in page anyway so removing the `position` option will clear your problem.

Also note syntax error..trailing comma in options object. This will break in IE

Comment: I removed the position param, no change. I only tried adding it because I was having problems in the first place.

Comment: try this version `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js`. Don't even need to download, just change src in tag. May need to update css if this works since 1.9 is a major version also

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a problem with the version of jQuery and jQuery UI that I was using together.

I found that this combination of versions stopped the dialog from 'sticking' to the top left hand corner:

- jQuery 1.8.2
- jQuery UI 1.10.1

Answer (score 1):

Change the jQuery UI version file that's in the user theme or plugin directory to new version of jQuery UI.  If the problem is not resolved, then copy the same jQuery UI version's minified files to `wp-includes/js/jquery/ui` folder (copy all the files in the ui folder).

Comment: Pawan, please leave clear, properly typed answers.  If you want people to be able to email you, you can add your email in your profile.  You don't need to mention it in answers.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a custom build of jQuery UI. In the [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/), make sure you've included the recommended components, including:

- Position
- Draggable

Additionally:

- Use your favourite HTML validator to make sure that your markup is correct
- Make sure the JavaScript error is not caused by some other code